# Most suitable CMS Framework for a company of 500 employees

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, frameworks, intranet

I would like to know if there is any recommendations of software or some type of framework that does the best suitable role for building an Intranet for my company.

Language Preferences:

HTML5
CSS3
PHP
MySQL

Architecture: Preferably MVC OOP

If you have any recommendations of what would be best suited, please let me know.

Would it be more ideal and a better option to just build it from the ground up?

I am not too sure how most companies do it so this is why I am asking.

Just looking for direction if you can help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you are about to develop a companies internal portal.Consider these tips:

A company with 500 personals probably use Active Directory  or another similar solution to store employees data to use it in emails and ticketing systems. So you will probably need to connect to Active Directory via LDAP to be able to use organized information about its users. I recommend pure PHP in this issue but ZEND provide some library to use LDAP as well.

Usage of this website is a bit different from internet websites.You will need to customized it to fit the companies needs and it will be difficult if you use a CMS that you are not thoroughly familiar with.So Developing it from the start point is not a bad idea.

I have experience in developing that and it expected to have a very good access level management to get controlled privileges to different departments to update different sections of the site.

So think about a very flexible and different website and chose a way that you are completely accustomed regardless of time consumption.

I hope these tips helped you.

Comment: thanks, this has given me enough information to give me the direction I need